# Garbage Face related information from .ply file

Tags: c++, opengl, mesh, 3d-modelling, assimp

I am trying to use [ASSIMP](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/) to extract the vertex/normal/face information from a ply file and then render it using OpenGL. Following is the code :

```
void PLYParser::importFile(std::string sFilePath)
{
    const aiScene* scene = aiImportFile (sFilePath.c_str(), aiProcess_Triangulate); // TRIANGLES!

    if (!scene)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: reading mesh %s\n" << sFilePath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    printf ("  %i animations\n", scene->mNumAnimations);
    printf ("  %i cameras\n", scene->mNumCameras);
    printf ("  %i lights\n", scene->mNumLights);
    printf ("  %i materials\n", scene->mNumMaterials);
    printf ("  %i meshes\n", scene->mNumMeshes);
    printf ("  %i textures\n", scene->mNumTextures);

      for (unsigned int m_i = 0; m_i < scene->mNumMeshes; m_i++)
      {
          const aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[m_i];
          printf ("    %i vertices in mesh\n", mesh->mNumVertices);
          g_point_count = mesh->mNumVertices;
          for (unsigned int v_i = 0; v_i < mesh->mNumVertices; v_i++)
          {
            if (mesh->HasPositions ())
            {
              const aiVector3D* vp = &(mesh->mVertices[v_i]);
              printf ("      vp %i (%f,%f,%f)\n", v_i, vp->x, vp->y, vp->z);
            }
            if (mesh->HasNormals ())
            {
              const aiVector3D* vn = &(mesh->mNormals[v_i]);
              printf ("      vn %i (%f,%f,%f)\n", v_i, vn->x, vn->y, vn->z);
            }
            if (mesh->HasTextureCoords (0))
            {
              const aiVector3D* vt = &(mesh->mTextureCoords[0][v_i]);
              printf ("      vt %i (%f,%f)\n", v_i, vt->x, vt->y);
            }
            if (mesh->HasTangentsAndBitangents ())
            {
              // NB: could store/print tangents here
            }

            if( mesh->HasFaces() )
            {
                const struct aiFace * vf = &(mesh->mFaces[m_i]);
                if (vf->mNumIndices == 3)
                {
                   printf ("      vf (%f,%f,%f)\n", vf->mIndices[0],vf->mIndices[1], vf->mIndices[2]);
                }
            }
          }
        }

      std::cout << "Parsing over" << std::endl ;
}
```

The vertex values are printing fine, but the face related information is kind of garbage, something of this sort :

```
vp 5107 (0.003326,0.079200,0.001920)
vf (0.000000,-0.000000,26815622223676999148426976713858144581866377154979840994523259353566101584147672957460702289212360863380556296293016572911077072166495943380764853993996288.000000)
```

**Q1.** Am I doing something wrong in the face related code ?

**Q2.** Also, there seems to be no normal related information in any of the ply files i parse. I have to manually calculate the normal for everything. Do ply have no normal information at all ?

**P.S. :** I have tried the code on several different ply files, I still get garbage values for the face information.

---

Edit 1 :

```
for (unsigned int m_i = 0; m_i < scene->mNumMeshes; m_i++)
      {
          const aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[m_i];
          printf ("    %i vertices in mesh\n", mesh->mNumVertices);
          g_point_count = mesh->mNumVertices;

          for (unsigned int v_i = 0; v_i < mesh->mNumFaces; v_i++)
          {
              if (mesh->HasFaces())
              {
                  for (unsigned int f_i = 0; f_i < mesh->mNumFaces; f_i++)
                  {
                      const struct aiFace* vf = mesh->mFaces + f_i;

                      if (vf->mNumIndices == 3)
                      {
                          printf("      vf (%u,%u,%u)\n", vf->mIndices[0], vf->mIndices[1], vf->mIndices[2]);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
        }
```

Am getting the alternate numbers as the output by changing code to above -

```
  vf (0,1,2)
  vf (3,4,5)
  vf (6,7,8)
  vf (9,10,11)
  vf (12,13,14)
  vf (15,16,17)
  ..
  ..
  and so on.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1**.

First issue:

```
printf ("      vf (%f,%f,%f)\n", vf->mIndices[0], vf->mIndices[1], vf->mIndices[2]);
```

The type of `vf->mIndices` is `unsigned int*`, so the format specifier `%f` is wrong, it should be `%u`. Try this instead:

```
printf ("      vf (%u,%u,%u)\n", vf->mIndices[0], vf->mIndices[1], vf->mIndices[2]);
```

Second issue:

You need to iterate over the list of faces of the mesh just like it is currently done for the list of vertices. Simply remove the current code dealing with the faces in the vertex loop, and add another loop for faces (at the same level as the one for vertices), like this:

```
for (unsigned int v_i = 0; v_i < mesh->mNumVertices; v_i++)
{
    // ...
}

if (mesh->HasFaces())
{
    for (unsigned int f_i = 0; f_i < mesh->mNumFaces; f_i++)
    {
        const struct aiFace* vf = mesh->mFaces + f_i;

        if (vf->mNumIndices == 3)
        {
            printf("      vf (%u,%u,%u)\n", vf->mIndices[0], vf->mIndices[1], vf->mIndices[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

**A2**.

There can be normal information specified for each vertex (3 additional `float` properties per vertex element named `nx`, `ny` and `nz`) in a PLY file. Since the format is flexible, normal per face could also be specified in a similar way. It all depends on what has been exported by the tool used to generate this file.

Comment: Now it is printing only this values for every face : `vf (0,1,2)`

Comment: @AmitTomar I had missed another major issue in your code, please see the latest edit.

Comment: I did the necessary modification, but its printing alternate numbers now. Please check the edit.

Comment: @AmitTomar What makes you think these numbers are wrong? Did you compare with the data stored in your PLY files?

Comment: mm.. I tried this code over many ply files and it gave same output for everyone of them. Face information in the files doesnt seem to sequential at all to me.

Comment: @AmitTomar 1. You should really compare the indices of the facets with the one from the PLY files (else how do you know the result is correct or not?) 2. These numbers are indices referring to the list of vertices, so it's not shocking that these indices are in sequence. 3. Check the OpenGL sample (line 200-223): https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/samples/SimpleOpenGL/Sample_SimpleOpenGL.c